# Simplest VPN setup for iphone on Debian Linux?

Tags: linux, debian, vpn, iphone

I have a Debian server that I would like to use as a VPN server for my iphone. I don't need multiple users or bullet proof security. All I'm really looking for is good enough protection to make reading traffic over open wifi nontrivial, but I'm not trying to protect data that requires next to unbreakable encryption. I've looked at the answer to the following question
[How to start setting up a VPN server for smart phone clients?](https://serverfault.com/questions/166521/how-to-start-setting-up-a-vpn-server-for-smart-phone-clients)
but openswan looks like more work then I'm willing to put in. Are there any ways to easily configure a L2TP VPN network on Linux without manually editing configuration files? If not how insecure is pptp? I may wind up biting the bullet and installing pfSense on a VM and running it from home but if it's not too much trouble would like to run the VPN from my Debian box.

Comment: Jailbreak isn't needed anymore. Theres an app for that (now) ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the Debian Wiki: http://wiki.debian.org/HowTo/iPhoneVPNServer. This describes how to implement a VPN server using the L2TP over IPsec protocol.

Answer (score -1):

You can install and use Openvpn as the server on your Debian box.

- Install Openvpn (it should be on the repos,so an apt-get install openvpn should be enough to install it)
- To configure use these docs: http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html
- Install this client on the iphone: http://www.guizmovpn.com/ and copy the config files there (generated following the docs)

Comment: Requires jailbroken iPhone (iOS device).